# Gaussian Filtering of accelerometer data

Tags: matlab, filtering, accelerometer, gaussian

I have accelerometer time series data and it is noisy. I wish to apply some low pass filters to remove noise using MATLAB. I found a very good answer at this link with very neat MATLAB Code [(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773542/matlab-filter-noisy-ekg-signal) [MATLAB: filter noisy EKG signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773542/matlab-filter-noisy-ekg-signal)). The syntax it provides is:

```
window = 7;

h = normpdf( -window:window, 0, fix((2*window+1)/6) );

y = filter(h, 1, x);
```

However, in this formulation, the mean is set to 0 and standard deviation to 2*window+1)/6.
My question is:

(1) for choosing 1-D Gaussian filter, how do we choose the mean and standard deviation parameters? Or is there any other better way to understand this solution.

(2) If the window size is N then should h be written as h=normpdf(-N:N, 0, fix(2*N+1)/(N-1)));

Right now I do not have access to Signal Processing toolbox in MATLAB.
Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: Is your question how to use the normpdf function?

Comment: My question is for gaussian smoothing using a window, how to set values for mean and standard deviation using filter command.

Comment: I think you need to look over the normpdf function first since your question entails the central moments of the gaussian