# Matlab & Simulink - replacing with octave and others to run digital filters

Tags: matlab, arduino

hello dear experts and user

i am currently planning to create a little system for Real Time ECGSignal Transmission [and] for Remote Monitoring

therefore i need to use Matlab and Simulink - (in order to run digital filters)

the question is: can i use the both systems free or do i need to find another systems and programs to substitute the above mentioned to realize the project;

matlab &/  Simulink - Simulation und Model-Based Design - MATLAB & Simulink
https://de.mathworks.com/products/simulink.html

what is wanted;  cf Real Time ECGSignal Transmission forRemote Monitoring
https://www.ijedr.org/papers/IJEDR1303068.pdf

Abstract-Our main objective is to implement a monitoring system which monitors the heart pulse of a patient. This work presents  a  novel  easy-to-use  system  intended  for  the  fast  and  non  invasive  monitoring  of  the  Lead  I  electrocardiogram (ECG)  signal  by  using  a  wireless  steering  wheel.  The  steering  wheel  used  here  is  a  prototype  model.    A  novel  heart  rate detection  algorithm  based  on  the  continuous  wavelet  transform  has  been  implemented,  which  is  specially  designed  to  be robust  against  the  most  common  sources  of  noise  and  interference  present  when  acquiring  the  ECG  in  the  hands.  Skin Electrodes were used to record the nerve voltages for monitoring the heart pulse. The voltages recorded will be sent to an instrumentation  amplifier  which  amplifies  the  signal,  and  then  to  a  filter  which  filters  the  noise.  Thus,  analog  signal  is given  to  Analog-to-Digital  Convertor  (ADC)  of  Arduino.  There,  analog  voltages  are  been  converted  to  digital  and  that digital  values  will  be  stored  in  the  EEPROM  of  Arduino.  The  values  stored  in  EEPROM  will  be  sent  to  PC  via  XBEE (IEEE 802.15.4) wirelessly and a serial port will be opened in the MATLAB by using a serial object. GUI is programmed to  make  the  user  interface  interactive  and  simple.  Using  the  real  time  plot,  I’ve  plotted  the  values  received  by  XBEE module and making a running waveform which displays when the MATLAB sent a query to Arduino.

love to hear from you

best regards

Comment: MATLAB is a commercial product. You could ask a representative about this. Don’t depend on strangers online for legal advice.

Comment: for those who end up here, if you are looking for free, libre, open-source software (FLOSS), alternatives to SIMULINK, you may check [this curated list](https://qr.ae/pGjKGA) I made quite a while ago.

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning to scavenge some existing code written in Matlab but want to transition to a free software solution instead, then [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is probably your best bet.
If you are looking for a Simulink equivalent compatible with Octave, I suggest you check out [this page](https://www.embecosm.com/2014/08/04/gnu-octave-and-circuit-simulation/). You may also want to read about [the Octave-Scilab co-simulation package](https://www.embecosm.com/2014/08/04/gnu-octave-and-circuit-simulation/), that would allow you to take advantage of Scilab's Simulink like package Xcos while working under Octave.

On the other hand, if you are writing your program from scratch, you could also go for [Python](https://www.python.org/), along with [the bms toolbox](https://pypi.org/project/bms/), which is presented as an "open-source equivalent to simulink in Python".

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773542/matlab-filter-noisy-ekg-signal
guess that i need to have access to the Signal Processing Toolbox - well then i could check out the Savitzky-Golay filter, namely the function sgolay. 
There's an accompanying demo, just run sgolaydemo. The following is an example to show the various ways we can apply filtering and de-noising to a signal.: Note some of these functions requires certain toolboxes to be present:
see more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773542/matlab-filter-noisy-ekg-signal - well what do you say: love to hear from you

Comment: great many thanks  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773542/matlab-filter-noisy-ekg-signal guess that i need to have access to the Signal Processing Toolbox - well then i could check out the Savitzky-Golay filter, namely the function sgolay. 
There's an accompanying demo, just run sgolaydemo. The following is an example to show the various ways we can apply filtering and de-noising to a signal. some of these functions requires certain toolboxes to be present:
see more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773542/matlab-filter-noisy-ekg-signal - love to hear from you - greetings

Comment: What noise are you trying to filter our from the ECG data? Is it 50/60Hz noise?